How come my custom URL in Strapi is causing a 405 error?
I would like to prefix all my strapi endpoints,
but I receive a 405 error on the /admin/register-admin endpoint
I have generated a brand new strapi project using
npx create-strapi-app@latest my-project --quickstart
I have added /strapi-v4 to my config/server.js, as I would like to prefix all my endpoints with this.
server.js file
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  app: {
    keys: env.array('APP_KEYS'),
  },
  url: '/strapi-v4',
  webhooks: {
    populateRelations: env.bool('WEBHOOKS_POPULATE_RELATIONS', false),
  },
});

when I run strapi for the first time with yarn start
and try create an admin user, I receive a 405 error

why is this?

I think that it's an issue on Strapi - would be worth checking if a GitHub issue exists.
If not create one

That's not a strapi issue. url aren't supposed to work like that:
Public url of the server. Required for many different features (ex: reset password, third login providers etc.). Also enables proxy support such as Apache or Nginx, example: https://mywebsite.com/api. The url can be relative, if so, it is used with http://${host}:${port} as the base url. An absolute url is however recommended.    
Documentation
It needs an absolute url  and reason for that it should reflect reverse proxy configuration for stuff like redirects work
e.g. https://example.com/strapi in there will result https://example.com/strapi/api.
Note
You would not be able to resolve above to https://example.com/api, you can check yarn strapi routes:list to see amount of routes you gonna need to resolve.
